# Publish content exactly 24 hours after it was created

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using sql server database.it has fields Isactive and created date...say created date=09/11/2010 5.00pm and its intial status=false by 10/11/2010 5.00pm it Isactive should be true.
How to acheive this

Comment: You'll need to set up a scheduled job to check and update these. Do you currently run any scheduled tasks e.g. as separate apps or using SQL Server Agent - would you have a preferred way of implementing it?

Comment: This should be done from your view. The view should query for posts that have matured.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I think you could base the "is record active" info on a date field instead of a bool field
e.g.

```
-- records that are active 24 hours after their created_date
SELECT AField
FROM SomeTable
WHERE created_date < DATEADD(dd, GETDATE(), -1)
```

Otherwise, you'll need to have a scheduled job to go through to update the bool flag for all rows that are now active - could need to be run very often if time is given down to full level of accuracy (hh:mm:ss.....) and you need it to become active pretty much straight away.